# p-calender From and To date validation

Tags: angular, primeng, angular-validation

Trying to validate FromDate and ToDate form control used p-calendar. Added some validation like below.

```
    export class SearchComponent implements OnInit {
    searchForm: FormGroup;
    dateFrom: Date;
    dateTo: Date;
                
    constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
     const dateFromValidation = (control: FormControl): ValidationErrors => this.dateChecker(control);
    const dateToValidation = (control: FormControl): ValidationErrors => this.dateChecker(control);
                
this.searchForm = this.formBuilder.group({            
   dateFrom: ['', dateFromValidation],
   dateTo: ['', dateToValidation]
 });
 }
            
 ngOnInit(): void {
 }
            
 dateFromValid(control: FormControl): ValidationErrors {
  let valueGreaterThanToDate = (fromDate: any): boolean => {
let fromDateValue = fromDate;
let toDateValue = this.searchForm.get('dateTo').value;
return fromDateValue > toDateValue;
};
                
if (!control || !this.searchForm ||
(control.value && this.searchForm.get('dateTo').value && !valueGreaterThanToDate(control.value))
) {
 return null as ValidationErrors;
}
                
let error: ValidationErrors = { dateFromInvalid: true };
return error;
}
                
dateToValid(control: FormControl): ValidationErrors {
 let valueLessThanFromDate = (toDate: any): boolean => {
 let toDateValue = toDate;
 let fromDateValue = this.searchForm.get('dateFrom').value;
                      return toDateValue < fromDateValue;
 };
                
 if (!control || !this.searchForm || (control.value && this.searchForm.get('dateFrom').value && !valueLessThanFromDate(control.value)) ) {
     return null as ValidationErrors;
  }
                
let error: ValidationErrors = { dateFromInvalid: true };
 return error;
 }
```

HTML looks like

```
<label for="">Dates from</label>
<p-calendar id="dateFromSelector" formControlName="dateFrom" inputId="basic" [showIcon]="true" inputId="icon" dateFormat="dd/mm/yy" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy" class="basic"></p-calendar>



<label for="">Dates to</label>
<p-calendar id="dateToSelector" formControlName="dateTo" inputId="basic" [showIcon]="true" inputId="icon" dateFormat="dd/mm/yy" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy" class="basic"></p-calendar>
```

I am trying to apply validation where fromDate > toDate. But FromDate control always turns red when I pick any date. Not sure why this is happening. Can anyone point me what went wrong here?

Updated
Form control

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but I think you have a logical issue in your validator function.

1. how I could see your two functions(`valueLessThanFromDatevalueLessThanFromDate` and `valueLessThanFromDate` ) conditions are the same so you can create and use only one function.
2. I think you need to compare your selected dates in milliseconds. if the value of your controls is Date String you need to do several things

- **convert the date string to the Date Object**
- **call `.getTime()` method to get the date in milliseconds**
- **compare these values**

I will put here a simple example but I can break the logic of your validator. **Please review the code before use.**

```
compareDates(toDateCtrl, fromDateCtrl): boolean {
    let fromDateValue = new Date(fromDateCtrl).getTime();
    let toDateValue = new Date(toDateCtrl).getTime();
    return fromDateValue > toDateValue;
}

// no need to use two functions
dateChecker(control: FormControl) {
    if (!this.searchForm) {
      return null;
    }
    const toDateCtrl = this.searchForm.get("dateTo");
    const fromDateCtrl = this.searchForm.get("dateFrom");
    if (
      !fromDateCtrl.value ||
      !toDateCtrl.value ||
      !this.compareDates(toDateCtrl.value, fromDateCtrl.value)
    ) {
      return null as ValidationErrors;
    }

    let error: ValidationErrors = { dateInvalid: true };
    return error;
}
```

and add `dateChecker` as a validator on your controls.

**Note: I have changed the error key name from `dateFromInvalid` to  - `dateInvalid`**

**Note: If you are building your controls by the FormBuilder, make sure you are putting the validators in the second array.**

https://stackblitz.com/edit/p-calendar-1242-evlnsu?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: I am getting Cannot read property 'get' error on this.searchForm.get('dateTo')

Comment: when you are adding your validator do `dateChecker.bind(this)`

Comment: const dateFromValidation = (control: FormControl): ValidationErrors => this.dateChecker(control); same for ToDate and this.searchForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      dateFrom: ['', dateFromValidation]});

Comment: can you change `searchForm` in `compareDates` change to the form name which you have in your component

Comment: if it didn't help can you append your form to the question?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226059/discussion-between-ashot-aleqsanyan-and-devsay).